# Disable oracle autocommit on close connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a question about Oracle autocommit on close connection event.

Information from oracle docs(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/java.121/e17657.pdf):

> If the auto-commit mode is disabled and you close the connection without explicitly committing or rolling back your last changes, then an implicit COMMIT operation is run.

So, I want to disable this feature programmatically in JDBC driver. I don't wan't do autocommit on connection close at least one transaction. Is it possible?

P.S. setAutoCommit change JDBC action. "Auto_Commit" start new transaction and call commit on every statement. It is not solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT. Possible duplicate : [Does Java Connection.close rollback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218350/does-java-connection-close-rollback)

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29), you should try to either commit or roll back before calling the close method. The results otherwise are implementation-defined.

Comment: Plz see again the question. Problem in autocommit on lost connection to db server. By default, Oracle commit transaction on lost connection

Comment: I need that DB server rollback this transaction automaticly then connection lost. JDBC driver can't do this because we haven't connection. This is server settings. And I think we can set property for every transaction and change on close connection action.

Comment: A lost connection to the server a different scenario from a connection.close. A connection.close does a implicit commit as the docs mention. A lost connection is handled by oracle's dead connection detection and does a rollback.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at the `setAutoCommit()` method of the `Connection` class. More details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)

Comment: Plz see again the question. Problem in autocommit on lost connection to db server. By default, Oracle commit transaction on lost connection.