# AutoCommit Flag of java.sql.Connection not working for SPARQL

Tags: oracle, jdbc, sparql, sqlconnection

I set "AutoCommit" flag for java.sql.Connection object as false when executing SPARQL Query but the flag is ignored. Given below is the part of the code that executes the Query.

```
    Connection conn;
    OracleDataSource oracleDataSource;
    try {
        oracleDataSource = new OracleDataSource();
        oracleDataSource.setURL("");
        oracleDataSource.setUser("");
        oracleDataSource.setPassword("");
        conn = oracleDataSource.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred in preparing connection: ", e.getMessage());
        throw (e);
    }

    String sparqlInsertQuery = "BEGIN SEM_APIS.UPDATE_MODEL('RDF_MODEL','xxxxxxxx'); END;";

    try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
        stmt.executeUpdate(sparqlInsertQuery);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Cannot Execute Query: ", e);
        throw (e);
    }

    //conn.commit();
    conn.close();
```

Eventhough I have added "conn.setAutoCommit(false);", the statement "stmt.executeUpdate(sparqlInsertQuery);" commits the Triples into the Model. Instead of SPARQL Query, if I use SQL Query, the "AutoCommit" flag value is considered and everything works fine.

Comment: i'm pretty sure the connection.close() forces a commit.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Only with Oracle (and maybe only older Oracle drivers), afaik, most JDBC drivers will rollback on close without an explicit commit when auto-commit is disabled.

Comment: Related: [Disable oracle autocommit on close connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263139/disable-oracle-autocommit-on-close-connection), [Does Java Connection.close rollback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218350/does-java-connection-close-rollback)

Comment: Hello everyone. This post is not about connection.close(). Its about AutoCommit flag works for SQL Query  but not for SPARQL Query. Even if I remove the statement conn.close(); I could see the Triples committed to the RDF Model.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I believe this post is not duplicate of the post you have tagged. As I mentioned, stmt.executeUpdate(sparqlInsertQuery); commits Triples to RDF Model which should not happen when conn.setAutoCommit(false); is set.