# Are resources closed before or after the finally?

Tags: java, java-7, finally, try-with-resources

In Java 7's try-with-resources, I don't know which order the finally block and the auto-closing happens. What's the order?

```
BaseResource b = new BaseResource(); // not auto-closeable; must be stop'ed
try(AdvancedResource a = new AdvancedResource(b)) {

}
finally {
    b.stop(); // will this happen before or after a.close()?
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The resource gets closed before catch or finally blocks.  See this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

> A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks just like an ordinary try statement. In a try-with-resources statement, any catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been closed.

To evaluate this is a sample code:

```
class ClosableDummy implements Closeable {
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("closing");
    }
}

public class ClosableDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ClosableDummy closableDummy = new ClosableDummy()) {
            System.out.println("try exit");
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("catch");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally");
        }


    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
try exit
closing
catch
finally
```

Comment: Crazy. So Try-with-resources is no good replacement for try-catch-finally when the resource is needed to handle the catch.

Comment: Resources don't needs handling in `catch` block.

Comment: The catch block may need the resource to complete it's task.

Comment: This is bad. I thought I could call `rollback()` in `finally` while using try-with-resources on an SQL connection. This way, I can't. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/218495/593146

Answer (score 1):

According to the JLS 13; [14.20.3.2. Extended try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2)

The finally block is the last to be executed:

> Furthermore, all resources will have been closed (or attempted to be
> closed) by the time the finally block is executed, in keeping with the
> intent of the finally keyword.