# Any workaround to avoid Stream has already closed when query for Oracle's bug?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm using ojdbc8 version 21.1.0.0 to be my JDBC. I have encountered issues that my connection stream will be closed everytime before calling `close()` when I execute my query that asked for long from resultSet for unknown reason, and my SQL runs fine on SQL developer. So I googled and see this bug reported on Oracle.

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/832903_1.html

Seem like it's a bug to their JDBCs? Does anyone know which version of ODBC8 doesn't have this bug? or other walkaround to avoid this bug?

==== Update ====

@Stephen C

Well, if you say so. But I don't think this would help anyway since the code itself is too simple to have such bug.

```
class Channel {
    private static DataSource ds = null;
    private static final String GET_ONE = "SELECT * FROM Channel WHERE Id=?";
    
    public Channel() {
        if(ds == null) {
            try {
                Context ctx = new InitialContext();
                ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/oracle");
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public HashMap<String, Object> getOne(String id) throws SQLException{
        HashMap<String, Object> result = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        try(Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(GET_ONE);){
            
            pstmt.setString(1, id);
            
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            
            if(rs.next()){
                result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                result.put("Time_Limit", rs.getLong("Time_Limit"));// recommended by @tgdavies
                result.put("Id", rs.getString("Id"));
                result.put("Name", rs.getString("Name"));
            }
        
        } catch(SQLException e){
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if(rs != null){
                try{
                    rs.close();
                } catch(SQLException e){}
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using a really old driver version, then upgrade.  If you're using the very latest version, and it seems buggy, then file a report and downgrade to the previous nearest stable version.

Comment: Have you tried the solution of reading the LONG value from the ResultSet first, before any other column? See https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/30/oracle-long-and-long-raw-causing-stream-has-already-been-closed-exception/

Comment: @tgdavies tried to read Long values first and still got that error

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen tried to downgrade to 19.7.0.0 and no luck for now

Comment: It is quite possible that the real cause is a bug in >your< code.  Either way, there's not much we can do to actually help you unless you show us the relevant code.  Ideally a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @StephenC Well, if you say so. Codes added, but I don't think this would help.

Comment: (FWIW - catching `SQLException` and rethrowing it is not necessary ... unless that is the remainder of some debugging ...)

Comment: @StephenC It was a custom error message, but not the case that I'm facing now. So I removed that.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what the problem is.

(Caveat: You haven't included a stacktrace, so I can't confirm this.  Furthermore, the link you posted is not open, so we can't see the details of the bug report you are talking about.)

```
    try(Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(GET_ONE);){
        
        pstmt.setString(1, id);
        
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        
        if(rs.next()){
            result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            result.put("Time_Limit", rs.getLong("Time_Limit"));// recommended by @tgdavies
            result.put("Id", rs.getString("Id"));
            result.put("Name", rs.getString("Name"));
        }
    
    } catch(SQLException e){
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if(rs != null){
            try{
                rs.close();
            } catch(SQLException e){}
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the `finally` gets executed AFTER the resources have been autoclosed.  So your code will be calling `rs.close()` after the `PreparedStatement` has been closed.  But closing the statement closes any result sets created from the statement.

Reference:

- [Are resources closed before or after the finally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129088/are-resources-closed-before-or-after-the-finally)

Possible solutions:

1. Treat the `ResultSet` as a resource too; e.g. with a nested *try with resource*.
2. Get rid of the `finally` ...

Comment: Something that I don't get it: I have it ignored with this line `} catch(SQLException e){}`, so I'm not suppose to get the stream closed exception while executing it. right?

Comment: Well ... it should be clear from the stacktrace where the `SQLException` is being thrown.  And it may be that it is happening within the try block, which would make my explanation incorrect.  (But a minrep should include a stacktrace ...)

Comment: And if this really is a driver bug, then you should be talking to Oracle Support about workarounds and alternative versions.

Comment: This looks like the right answer. Remove the finally block. You don't need it.