# Closes connection and creates a new one not to exceed max cursors after 295 inserts

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

A previous developer left this message in code.

It runs create statement and execute query and after 295 records it creates new connection.

Following is java code:

```
private void dbUpdate() throws SQLException, Exception {
        Statement st = null;
        String sql = "";
        int count = 0;
        try {
            getNewConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            for (Iterator it = sqlList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                if (count < 295) { //Closes connection and creates a new one so as not to exceed max cursors
                    count++;
                } else {
                    st.close();
                    conn.close();
                    getNewConnection();
                    count = 0;
                }
                sql = (String) it.next();
//                System.out.println(sql + " insert count=" + count);
                st = conn.createStatement();
                try {
                    st.executeQuery(sql);
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(LoadMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, sql);
                    Logger.getLogger(LoadMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
                    sb.append("\n").append("Error SQL:" + sql + "|LocalizedMessage:" +ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoadMain.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, sql);
            Logger.getLogger(LoadMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
            throw new SQLException(ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
//            Logger.getLogger(loadMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
            throw new Exception(ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                st.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LoadMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any logic behind re connection?
(Also developer set autocommit false but not seen committing or roll-backing but only st.close() methods.)

Could anyone please enlighten

Comment: seems developer tried to implement connection pooling

Comment: Use a proper dbcp

Comment: @user7294900: Also any idea why is autocommit set to false but it is not committing or rollbacking so how things are getting committed? does it commit on close?

Comment: Why do you do `executeQuery` when you don't need a ResultSet? If you did `executeUpdate` instead it would most likely not even accumulate all those cursors that you never close in the first place.

Comment: @Thilo: It is very very old code and i too thinking why use executeQuery over executeUpdate

Comment: @fatherazrael IIRC, the Oracle JDBC driver commits (instead of rollback) on connection close. It looks like the code is relying on that.

Comment: Why is that code using `executeQuery()` when it doesn't use the result set?

Answer (score 0):

Seems as the developer tried to implement connection pooling, which now can be integrated easily with DBCP/Hikari/other database connection pool.

You don't need to commit on DAO level/method, for example
if the code is called by a method with @Transactional or commit is handled on service level.

Also you can't rely that [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218350/does-java-connection-close-rollback) will commit or rollback, there can be different results with different oracle drivers

> According to the javadoc, you should try to either commit or roll back before calling the close method. The results otherwise are implementation-defined.

Comment: There is no @Transactionsl. It is complete Core Java Code

Comment: @fatherazrael the calling method(s) doesn't execute a commit? also maybe `getNewConnection()` is committing once per 256

Comment: No it does not. But data is there in table. So i was wonderous if close() executes commit?

Comment: @fatherazrael https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218350/does-java-connection-close-rollback

Comment: It says -> Oracle's JDBC driver commits on close() by default. You should not rely on this behaviour if you intend to write multi-platform JDBC code.

Comment: Close documentation says -> It is strongly recommended that an application explicitly commits or rolls back an active transaction prior to calling the close method. If the close method is called and there is an active transaction, the results are implementation-defined. (WHAT IS MEANING OF implementation defined?)

Comment: @fatherazrael means that you can't rely that close will commit or rollback, accepted answer is *According to the javadoc, you should try to either commit or roll back before calling the close method. The results otherwise are implementation-defined.*

Comment: @fatherazrael Implementation defined means it depends on the specific implementation of your JDBC driver and database what happens on connection close.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: O got it. So questions arises to which implementations do the same and which not. So it is bad practice then.